Replay IHeartRadio station URL in Python
I am trying to capture the IHeartRadio URL for a specific site and just replay it.
The replaying part I have down in python that's no issue.
the issue is actually capturing this URL!
I tried capturing it in WireShark, its all encrypted so I wasn't able to see any URLs. Mainly just TLS and encryption headers.
I tried capturing the request in burpsuite and I captured a few but still wasn't able to replay anything I captured and wasn't sure what the identifier of a station is.
I next tried Fiddler and I captured a handful of requests when turning on a station.
Still no luck figuring out what to replay and identifier the station.

I read an old post and it said to try this: but this must be an old version of how IHRH use to be.
Use a filter and type in tcp contains "ihrh"

Open all packets which include the link. *NOTE: Ignore any text which contains "ihrh" we are looking for a link
Find server link (ex. c13.prod.playlists.ihrhls.com) *NOTE: make sure it is "c" and a number like "c13" NOT "cdn" or anything else
Go in internet explorer and go to stream on iheart radio
Look at url and notice the code (ex. _h_ttps://www.iheart.com/live/channel-933-241/?autoplay=true&pname=fire&campid=local&callletters=khts-fm)


The purpose of HTTPS is to prevent that someone intercepting network traffic can read the content like URls. That is the reason why Fiddler only shows you the "tunnel to" connection establishment requests but no actual web URLs. Unless you manage to make the used IHeart player (is it a program and if yes for which OS, or hardware?) trust the proxy root CA certificate you won't see any request data.

I was able to figure this out.
I was able to go to the network tab and in the JSON data I was able to pull out the URL streams that automatically start station when its entered into a browser
